# config mongodb in spring, application.properties OR AbstractMongoConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, configuration

We can use AbstractMongoConfiguration (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoConfiguration.html) to do the mongodb configuration. Also, we can use application.properties to do config (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an opinion-based question and answer.

The answer is simple: My opinion is that spring-boot really encourages you to use application.properties whenever possible. So, I'd says:

> it is better to use application.properties with spring-boot, rather
>   than java config

spring-boot's AutoConfiguration happens so early in the spring lifecycle, that it is nearly impossible not to use application.properties (to allow AutoConfigurations to load their properties).

Also, spring-cloud-config allows loading properties remotely, so that would be another possible future advantage of using this mechanism.

Comment: I have applied my properties in application properties but cloud foundry does not acknowledge it. It does not do the mongodb connection. Even when I bind the mongo db that is offered on cloud foundry

Comment: Not sure what you mean "cloud foundry does not acknowledge it". Spring Boot is the one loading its "application.properties" files.  See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cloud-deployment.html#cloud-deployment-cloud-foundry AND https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/27/12-factor-app-style-backing-services-with-spring-and-cloud-foundry.  Mind you, I never deployed to Cloud Foundry, so perhaps you are right. It may just be the wording: cloud foundry doesn't "directly" load the application.properties, it's done by spring-boot.